# c# global keyboard hook with Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint COMException

Tags: c#, exception, powerpoint, global, keyboard-hook

I'm using the full class provided as best answer in: [C# Hook Global Keyboard Events - .net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281223/c-sharp-hook-global-keyboard-events-net-4-0) without any changes to it. However, when pressing a key when focussed on the powerpoint, I get the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

I open the powerpoint by:

```
PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = (PowerPoint.Presentation)PowerPointItems[0];
PowerPoint.Application application = presentation.Application;
PowerPoint.SlideShowSettings settings = presentation.SlideShowSettings;
settings.ShowType = (PowerPoint.PpSlideShowType)1;
settings.ShowPresenterView = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow sw = settings.Run();
sw.View.AcceleratorsEnabled = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
presentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide(1);
presentation.SlideShowWindow.View.FirstAnimationIsAutomatic();
```

The callback function looks like:

```
private static void Kh_KeyDown(Keys key, bool Shift, bool Ctrl, bool Alt)
{
   Console.WriteLine("a");
   PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = (PowerPoint.Presentation)PowerPointItems[0];
   Console.WriteLine("b");
   int nr_slides = presentation.Slides.Count;
   Console.WriteLine("c");
}
```

However, while a and b are printed in the output, c is not but the exception is. This makes me think for some reason the exception is thrown because of the line

```
int nr_slides = presentation.Slides.Count;
```

Any thought on why this could be the case?

The code provided on [C# Hook Global Keyboard Events - .net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281223/c-sharp-hook-global-keyboard-events-net-4-0):

```
public class KeyboardHook : IDisposable
{
    bool Global = false;

    public delegate void ErrorEventHandler(Exception e);
    public delegate void LocalKeyEventHandler(Keys key, bool Shift, bool Ctrl, bool Alt);
    public event LocalKeyEventHandler KeyDown;
    public event LocalKeyEventHandler KeyUp;
    public event ErrorEventHandler OnError;

    public delegate int CallbackDelegate(int Code, IntPtr W, IntPtr L);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct KBDLLHookStruct
    {
        public Int32 vkCode;
        public Int32 scanCode;
        public Int32 flags;
        public Int32 time;
        public Int32 dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookType idHook, CallbackDelegate lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);
    
  
    [DllImport("user32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr idHook);

    [DllImport("user32", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();
    
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    public enum HookType : int
    {
        WH_JOURNALRECORD = 0,
        WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 1,
        WH_KEYBOARD = 2,
        WH_GETMESSAGE = 3,
        WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4,
        WH_CBT = 5,
        WH_SYSMSGFILTER = 6,
        WH_MOUSE = 7,
        WH_HARDWARE = 8,
        WH_DEBUG = 9,
        WH_SHELL = 10,
        WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE = 11,
        WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12,
        WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13,
        WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
    }

    private IntPtr HookID = IntPtr.Zero;
    CallbackDelegate TheHookCB = null;

    //Start hook
    public KeyboardHook(bool Global)
    {
        this.Global = Global;
        TheHookCB = new CallbackDelegate(KeybHookProc);
        if (Global)
        {
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            HookID = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, TheHookCB,
                hInstance, //0 for local hook. or hwnd to user32 for global
                0); //0 for global hook. eller thread for hooken
        }
        else
        {
            HookID = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_KEYBOARD, TheHookCB,
                IntPtr.Zero, //0 for local hook. or hwnd to user32 for global
                GetCurrentThreadId()); //0 for global hook. or thread for the hook
        }
    }

    public void test()
    {
        if (OnError != null) OnError(new Exception("test"));
    }
    bool IsFinalized = false;
    ~KeyboardHook()
    {
        if (!IsFinalized)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(HookID);
            IsFinalized = true;
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!IsFinalized)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(HookID);
            IsFinalized = true;
        }
    }
    [STAThread]
    //The listener that will trigger events
    private int KeybHookProc(int Code, IntPtr W, IntPtr L)
    {
        
        KBDLLHookStruct LS = new KBDLLHookStruct();
        if (Code < 0)
        {
            return CallNextHookEx(HookID, Code, W, L);
        }
        try
        {
            if (!Global)
            {
                if (Code == 3)
                {
                    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

                    int keydownup = L.ToInt32() >> 30;
                    if (keydownup == 0)
                    {
                        if (KeyDown != null) KeyDown((Keys)W, GetShiftPressed(), GetCtrlPressed(), GetAltPressed());
                    }
                    if (keydownup == -1)
                    {
                        if (KeyUp != null) KeyUp((Keys)W, GetShiftPressed(), GetCtrlPressed(), GetAltPressed());
                    }
                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Down: " + (Keys)W);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                KeyEvents kEvent = (KeyEvents)W;

                Int32 vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32((IntPtr)L); //Leser vkCode som er de første 32 bits hvor L peker.

                if (kEvent != KeyEvents.KeyDown && kEvent != KeyEvents.KeyUp && kEvent != KeyEvents.SKeyDown && kEvent != KeyEvents.SKeyUp)
                {
                }
                if (kEvent == KeyEvents.KeyDown || kEvent == KeyEvents.SKeyDown)
                {
                    if (KeyDown != null) KeyDown((Keys)vkCode, GetShiftPressed(), GetCtrlPressed(), GetAltPressed());
                }
                if (kEvent == KeyEvents.KeyUp || kEvent == KeyEvents.SKeyUp)
                {
                    if (KeyUp != null) KeyUp((Keys)vkCode, GetShiftPressed(), GetCtrlPressed(), GetAltPressed());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (OnError != null) OnError(e);
            //Ignore all errors...
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(HookID, Code, W, L);

    }

    public enum KeyEvents
    {
        KeyDown = 0x0100,
        KeyUp = 0x0101,
        SKeyDown = 0x0104,
        SKeyUp = 0x0105
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static public extern short GetKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys nVirtKey);

    public static bool GetCapslock()
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(GetKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.CapsLock)) & true;
    }
    public static bool GetNumlock()
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(GetKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.NumLock)) & true;
    }
    public static bool GetScrollLock()
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(GetKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Scroll)) & true;
    }
    public static bool GetShiftPressed()
    {
        int state = GetKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.ShiftKey);
        if (state > 1 || state < -1) return true;
        return false;
    }
    public static bool GetCtrlPressed()
    {
        int state = GetKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.ControlKey);
        if (state > 1 || state < -1) return true;
        return false;
    }
    public static bool GetAltPressed()
    {
        int state = GetKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Menu);
        if (state > 1 || state < -1) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to catch the COMException, interrogate `ErrorCode` (HRESULT) property, and search for the error code definition; this will provide direction on how to troubleshoot the issue further.

Reference: [COMException Class: Handling a COMException exception on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception?view=net-6.0#handling-a-comexception-exception)

One idea, without knowing the error code, is this interaction might need to occur on the thread which instantiated the control.  You might be able to resolve this by using Invoke or BeginInvoke.

[Control.BeginInvoke Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

If you add more details to the question I will try to provide a better answer.